# Using PRISM to share the same ViewModels between Views

Tags: mvvm, prism

I'm trying to develop a PRISM WPF application where I am going to have two or more views depending on the same ViewModel. At first I thought of using Unity to do an injection through the view's constructor and within the constructor set the DataContext. That idea was dismissed by the team because they want nothing in the code-behind. Moreover, the views are using a ViewModelLocator that is Autowired to the ViewModel. So then my only other thought doing a Module with a single view, but then how do I go about sharing the same ViewModel between modules if I'm using Unity IOC? Any ideas with some kind of example?

Answer (score 0):

Don't share ViewModels instances between views.  Just load data as you need it.  But if you must shoot yourself in the foot there are many ways to do it.  The easiest would be to register your ViewModel as a singleton in your container.

Comment: I thought of that idea immediately when I was first given this task, but the team wasn't loving this idea either. Worse comes to worst, I told them that we may have to scrap what they got and go with your [Pluralsight course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-problems-solutions) on loading dependent views

Comment: If your team likes the idea of sharing VM instances across different views, then you have bigger problems

Comment: Can you please explain why sharing ViewModels instances is not the best?